# How do I handle errors from cleanup / destroy functions

Tags: c

I am struggeling with cleanup code which returns error codes/objects. Examples on how to cleanup a function usually just call free() at the end or anything not returning an error. But a destroy function of a module could be complex and maybe also return errors. Even close() could return a error although often unchecked.

How do you handle situations like that? Do you just log but ignore the error otherwise, do you return the error code of the *_destroy function at the end? Would you somehow restructure the code? What is the recommended solution here?

Thank you

```
int moduleA_create(moduleA *handle, int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4);
int moduleA_destroy(moduleA handle);
int moduleB_create(moduleB *handle, const char *param);
int moduleB_destroy(moduleB handle);

int some_function(void) {
  int r;
  moduleA a;
  moduleB b;

  r = moduleA_create(&a, 1, 2, 3, 4);
  if (r < 0) goto EXIT_A;

  r = moduleB_create(&b, "some string");
  if (r < 0) goto EXIT_B;

  // more code

  // this could return error
  moduleB_destroy(b);
EXIT_B:
  // this could return error
  moduleA_destroy(a);
EXIT_A:

  return r;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do in that case other than log the error so that a future programmer can know to reproduce the fault, figure out the underlying reason why the call failed, and fix it.

Comment: Side note, but your existing error handling already looks wrong.  If `moduleA_create` fails, you probably shouldn't call `moduleA_destroy`.

Comment: You are right of course, I will edit my question. Thank you

Comment: It really depends on your application. eg, in embedded land, if there's a critical error in initializing eg a task, I will maybe shoot out a message on a debug UART port (if it's initialized) or blink an LED at a given rate or something. I wouldn't worry about destroying B or whatever because clearly there's a hardware fault or firmware fault. If less critical, you should clean up everything and return an error message to the caller. You should somehow make it so the destroy can't error, or if it does return a different error code.

Comment: That is a programmer's life. Often error handling requires more work than the actual program logic :)

Comment: Note that in C++, destructors which generate exceptions are anathema.  Avoid having destructors fail.  When a destructor (cleanup routine) can't do its job, log an error if error logging is part of the application anyway (whether to a file, standard error or something like syslog), and otherwise ignore the error (but don't crash because of the failure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you just log but ignore the error otherwise, do you return the error code of the *_destroy function at the end? Would you somehow restructure the code? What is the recommended solution here?

It's highly situation-dependent, as, indeed, is error-handling in general.  Often, there's not much you *can* do other than emit messages / different return values, and possibly abort the program.

If the error happens in the context of shutting down the application, as your particular example suggests to me, then I would be inclined to attempt to continue the standard shutdown sequence.  A diagnostic message to `stderr` *might* be warranted.  A non-zero exit status *might* be warranted.  Or not.

For example, I usually just ignore failures to `close()` / `fclose()` files that were only read, but I would definitely emit a warning or error message on failing to close a file that the program had created or written to, on account of the possibility that the program's operations on the file might not have actually been carried out as intended.

Comment: One distinction to make would be “Was this cleanup/destroy function doing something for the user?” As you mention, closing an output file (and hence flushing its buffer, ensure data is sent to the device) matters. Returning resources to the operating system does not matter. If it matters, it ought to be communicated to the user one way or another. If it does not matter, but it could indicate some bug, it ought to be communicated to the responsible developer. (Although the number of log messages reporting such errors in a system log these days is insane.)

Answer (score 0):

"Would you somehow restructure the code?"

Rather than using `goto` with its opportunity for code to be wrong, sequenced progress may require undoing what's been done (as best one can) in exactly the reverse order.

Below is a *sketch* that demonstrates one "successful" trial run, and one run deliberately coded to fail on the 3rd step. It uses the conditional operator for brevity, and always the return code "-1" from teardown functions. This is just a sketch.

Notice that the progress/teardown function invocations are proximate to one another and that the sequence reverses itself.

This code would, of course, be altered to meet needs. It provides a schema that does not require `goto` labels to be ordered in code, distant from where they may be "used". This is one alternative to "restructuring the code".

```
int doPh1R() { puts( "doPh1R" ); return -1; }
int doPh1F() { puts( "doPh1F" ); return 1; }

int doPh2R() { puts( "doPh2R" ); return -1; }
int doPh2F() { puts( "doPh2F" ); return 1; }

int doPh3R() { puts( "doPh3R" ); return -1; }
int doPh3F() {
    static bool cond = true;
    if( cond ) {
        puts( "doPh3F" );
        cond = !cond; // boobytrap the next execution
        return 1;
        }

    puts( "doPh3F Error" );
    return -1;
}

int doSomething( int trial ) {
    enum { done, phase1, phase2, phase3, run };

    int dir = 1;
    int err = -1; // pessimism
    printf( "\tTrial #%d\n", trial );
    for( int phase = phase1; phase != done; phase += dir )
        switch( phase ) {
            case phase1:
                dir = dir==1 ? doPh1F() : doPh1R();
                break;
            case phase2:
                dir = dir==1 ? doPh2F() : doPh2R();
                break;
            case phase3:
                dir = dir==1 ? doPh3F() : doPh3R();
                break;
            case run:
                puts( "run" );
                dir = -1;
                err = 0;
                break;
        }
    return err;
}

int main() {
    puts( doSomething(1) ? "\tFail" : "\tSuccess" ); // One good run
    puts( doSomething(2) ? "\tFail" : "\tSuccess" ); // One bad run

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
        Trial #1
doPh1F
doPh2F
doPh3F
run
doPh3R
doPh2R
doPh1R
        Success
        Trial #2
doPh1F
doPh2F
doPh3F Error
doPh2R
doPh1R
        Fail
```